# Signup In Asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

i download templates from internet and use it but when click on  signup the button data save into database but without any value
like this in database

```
MemID   MemName  MemPass  Email  Phnenumber UserTypeID
 2                                  NULL          NULL
 3                                  NULL          NULL
 NULL  NULL NULL    NULL          NULL          NULL
```

here is template code

```
<div id="container_demo" >

<a class="hiddenanchor" id="toregister"></a>
<a class="hiddenanchor" id="tologin"></a>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="login" class="animate form">
        <form  action="WebForm1.aspx" autocomplete="on">
            <h1>Log in</h1>
            <p>
                <label for="username" class="uname" data-icon="u" > Your email or 
               username </label>
                <input id="username" name="username" required="required" type="text"
            placeholder="myusername or mymail@mail.com"/>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="password" class="youpasswd" data-icon="p"> Your password 
           </label>
                <input id="password" name="password" required="required" 
          type="password" placeholder="eg. X8df!90EO" />
            </p>
            <p class="keeplogin">
                <input type="checkbox" name="loginkeeping" id="loginkeeping" 
            value="loginkeeping" />
                <label for="loginkeeping">Keep me logged in</label>
            </p>
            <p class="login button">
                <input type="submit" value="Login" />
            </p>
            <p class="change_link">
                Not a member yet ?
                <a href="#toregister" class="to_register">Join us</a>
            </p>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div id="register" class="animate form">
        <form  action="#tologin" autocomplete="on">
            <h1> Sign up </h1>

            <p>
                <label for="usernamesignup" class="uname" data-icon="u">Your 
    username</label>
                <input id="usernamesignup" runat="server" name="usernamesignup"
      required="required" type="text" placeholder="mysuperusername690" />
            </p>
             <p>
                <label for="passwordsignup" class="youpasswd" data-icon="p">Your 
           password </label>
                <input id="password1" name="passwordsignup" runat="server" 
       required="required" type="password" placeholder="eg. X8df!90EO"/>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="emailsignup" class="youmail" data-icon="e" > Your 
        email</label>
                <input id="emailsignup" name="emailsignup" runat="server" 
                required="required" type="text" placeholder="mysupermail@mail.com"/>
            </p>


          <%--  <p>
                <label for="passwordsignup_confirm" class="youpasswd"  
                  data-icon="p">Please 
                confirm your password </label>
                <input id="passwordsignup_confirm" runat="server 
        name="passwordsignup_confirm" required="required" type="password" 
             placeholder="eg. X8df!90EO"/>
            </p>--%>
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            <p class="signin button">
                <input type="button"  value="submitt"  runat="server" 
                onserverclick="Btn_SignUp_Click" />
            </p>
            <p class="change_link"> 
                Already a member ?
                <a href="#tologin" class="to_register"> Go and log in </a>
            </p>
        </form>
    </div>

</div>
```

i use this form please check this link 
[template link](http://www.ajaxshake.com/plugin/EN/1069/7d65a566/registration-form-with-html5-and-css3-registrationform.html)...

and i also create sp and function

```
sp ALTER procedure [dbo].[spinsert] @MemName nvarchar(50), @MemPass nvarchar(50),   
       @Email nvarchar(50) as insert into MemberAccount (MemName,MemPass,Email) values
        (@MemName,@MemPass,@Email)
```

function

```
 protected void Btn_SignUp_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            abb.Registration(usernamesignup.Value, password1.Value, emailsignup.Value);
            //ab.usernameexist(txt_fullname.Value);
            Label1.Text = ("UserName already exist");
            //cc.getusername(TextBox1.Text);
            //sig.Text = ("Register Success");
            Label1.Text = ("Signup Success");
        }
        catch
        {
            Label1.Text = ("SignUp failed");

        }
        usernamesignup.Value = "";
        password1.Value = "";
        emailsignup.Value = "";

    }
```

Comment: show the code of `abb.Registration` function.

Comment: Did you validate the data that comes in when a registration is made ? Show your `abb.Registration` code. Seems like you miss the validation. Do you have any validation logic in your html ?

Comment: @sACHIN this is the code...  public void Registration(string MemName, string MemPass, string Email)
        {
            db.ExecuteNonQuery("spinsert", new object[] { MemName, MemPass, Email});
        }

Comment: i call class like this in form in aspx...        ClassLibrary1.Class1 abb = new ClassLibrary1.Class1();

Comment: `ExecuteNonQuery` has parameters?? are you sure that you are using correct function.

Comment: yes............. i use this same another project and this is working but in this i dont know why it is not working